# Managing autolayout constraints for a chat view

Tags: ios, swift2, chat, ios-autolayout, xcode7.3

I'm creating a chat view, and currently trying to design the cell based on autolayout. My main problem is that, there is an image view and just below there's a label for chat text which go multiple line, and if there's no image only text should display and if there's no text only image should display. Image should be 60% of cell width and 40% in height. Below is my cell design, I've added background color to each view for clarity.

[image]

But by giving proportional height, I'm not able to set its height programatically. So currently I tried giving a fixed height for image view and manage it programmatically in the code. Below is my code where I adjust imageview and chat text height.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : ChatViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("chatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatViewCell

        cell.fullNameLabel.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].0
        cell.fullDateLabel.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].1
        cell.chatSentStatusLabel.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].2
        cell.chatTimeLabel.text = tempArray[indexPath.row].3


        let chatBubbleData1 = tempArray[indexPath.row].4

        if (chatBubbleData1.image == nil)
        {
            cell.chatImageHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        else
        {
            cell.chatImageHeightConstraint.constant = 150

        }

        cell.chatTextContainerView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        cell.chatTextContainerView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.chatBubbleView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        cell.chatBubbleView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.chatImageView.image = chatBubbleData1.image
        cell.userPointerView.colors = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        cell.userPointerView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

        cell.chatImageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        cell.chatImageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

        if (chatBubbleData1.text?.characters.count > 0)
        {
            cell.chatText?.numberOfLines = 0 // Making it multiline
            cell.chatText?.text = chatBubbleData1.text
            cell.chatText?.sizeToFit()
            cell.chatTextContainerHeightConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(cell.chatText.frame)+20
        }
        else
        {
            cell.chatText?.text = ""
            cell.chatTextContainerHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        }

        cell.setNeedsDisplay()
        return cell
    }
```

This is the result now

[image]

The multiline doesn't seems to work. I'm not sure if I'm following the best approach. If anybody has any solutions or any suggestions, please let me know.

*PS: Please don't suggest any third parties like JSQMessagesViewController. I'm already aware of those. I'm doing this as part of learning.*

Comment: You have set the fixed height constraint for chat label ?

Comment: No, I've only set top, bottom, leading and trailing to its superview.

Answer (score 0):

You just put a bottom constraint for all the components in the cell.
and call delegate methods of table view (EstimatedRowHight and HightForRow).
it will return the exact hight of the cell.and you can also customise whether it display or not..

remember that text labels should had the bottom constrain property with respect the other components.Hope you get what i meant.

Comment: Yes, I've put the bottom constraints, but the problem is, I've to reduce heights of image or text to 0 based on data, at that time it create problems.

Answer (score 0):

If UIImageView and UILabel will never be shown both in the same cell, you could remove all constraints relations between them and make each in relation only with superview. Then with some code you can manage UIImageView or UILabel visibility and calculate proper height for each cell in CollectionView/TableView delegate method.

Comment: If there's image and text, then both will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your line

```
cell.chatTextContainerHeightConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(cell.chatText.frame)+20
```

Instead of getting chatText.frame height your should manually calculate the height. I used following function to calculate cell height:

```
+ (CGFloat)calculateCellHeightForText:(NSString *)text cellWidth:(CGFloat)cellWidth {
    CGFloat maxWidth = cellWidth;
    CGSize textSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"CALIBRI" size:17]}
                                         context:nil].size;
    return textSize.height;
}
```